Atomic Redis transaction for idempotency required for database inserts using Redis Springboot 3
We are using springboot 3.2.5 and spring data jpa to insert data into RDBMS.
Now there is a requirement to ensure duplicate data does not get inserted into RDBMS.
So we have to first check if data record is inserted already based on the key, and it checks if Redis contains the key, if it contains the key, return the identifier of the entity saved.
If the key is not existing in redis - first time hitting a request, create a new redis key and then save the key in the Redis, then insert data into RDBMS and once the insert succeeds update the identifier into redis value corresponding to that key.
We are using Redis and need to ensure that the check for key existence check and creation of new key (if absent) in an atomic operation - means this needs to happen in a single transaction. We are using spring data redis 3.2.X JSON which has Lettuce included. Please help.
We are currently using simple Redis commands like set and get using lettuce ProtocolKeyword for executing commands. Redis documentation suggests using MULTI and EXEC but not sure if these are possible with Lettuce (Lettuce documentation is not accessible)
There are approaches using pipelines and transactions and we are inclined towards transactions for the atomicity. I have not find a viable way to do so in code though.

Your big challenge here is that you want to atomically

Check Redis for the presence of the key
Insert the data into your database
Set the data in Redis

Now, you are going between two different unlinked datasources, so a purely atomic mechanism simply isn't possible, MULTI/EXEC will not help because you are going between these data sources. However you can ensure there's only one writer at a time using a distributed lock.
Let's assume you are sticking to your simple string keys, let's call the data key you want to use key:1
Lock the key
use SET with the NX command with the EX option to post a timeout on some lock key e.g. key:1:lock - e.g.
SET key:1:lock 1 NX EX 10

this will write the value 1 to the key ONLY if the key doesn't already exist in Redis and it will automatically expire the key after 10 seconds (in case your thread dies for some reason)
Check if you get a response back
If you receive an OK result, this means that you have acquired the lock, if you get null back then you know that a different thread has acquired the lock, you can either terminate here or back off and try again later
Write your data to the database
You can now write your database - this should be pretty self explanatory
Write your Data Key and delete the lock key
Now you will write the actual data to Redis, and you will delete the lock key, allowing other threads to update the data, you can do this with a SET and an UNLINK
SET key:1 your_data
UNLINK key:1:lock


Thanks for taking out the time to have a look at this, I am reading and thinking of the implementation you have suggested. Though I'd like to add one thought that is the requirement to use REDIS JSON- we are told to save the keys to prevent other threads from altering our data, multiple insertion in RDBMS. And I cannot find the Unlink command or (MULTI/EXEC/WATCH commands for that matter) in the documentation for REDIS JSON - https://redis.io/docs/latest/operate/oss_and_stack/stack-with-enterprise/json/commands/

Command docs can be found at redis.io/commands for each of these commands.
MULTI/EXEC/WATCH will not do much to ensure that atomicity of these operations, because you are going between Redis and your RDBMS.

Thanks slorello for your feedback, There are 2 steps to the atomicity we are trying to achieve - Step 1 - Checking if key already exists and Setting the new key - these two operations we intend to do as atomic from Redis Step 2 - Making sure that once the RDBMS insert is done, updating the value of the key set in redis by the Identifier created in the database, or else revert redis key creation. Step 1 needs to be in a redis transaction and Both Steps need to be atomic in the sense that Redis and RDBMS both succeed or both fail, Now would the solution for locking key solve both challenges?

MULTI/EXEC doesn't permit you to check any sort of state in Redis when you are determining whether to something or not, so specifically for what you are trying to do here, you would need to use a script/function: https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/interact/programmability/ for step 1, then you can come back through and just set the ID with step 2.
I am very skeptical of this approach though as it doesn't allow any sort of recovery if there's a failure between steps 1 and 2, IMO the blueprint I laid above would still be best approach.

Naturally you could use your data structure of choice when writing your data. But if you experience any sort of interruption after you've written the first part of the data but before you've written the second part of your data, your data key is now corrupted and you've given yourself no obvious means of recovery.
